# Как привести слайдер в такой вид как на картинке?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

[тут у нас сайт на котором мой слайдер](http://104.248.204.156/)

[image: а вот как он должен выглядеть]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос в виде картинки бесполезен для базы знаний

Answer (score 1):

С помощью каскадных таблиц стилей (CSS).

У Вас стили на свайпер подключаются здесь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.S. Из этих двух строчек достаточно одной, т.к. это одно и то же. Разница только в размере.

Comment: ок тогда другой вопрос, откуда у слайдера берутся эти стили ?
<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" style="width: 268.667px; margin-right: 30px;">Slide 1</div>

Comment: Обновил ответ выше.